# Simple question on db design

Tags: database

We have 2 tables: FILES and FILEHISTORY defined like this:

```
FILES
( FILEID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 FILEBODY LOB,
 FILENAME VARCHAR)

FILEHISTORY
( FILEID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  FILENAME VARCHAR,
 some other fields)
```

That is, filehistory has extended properties saying what has been done to file with FILEID.

Now, our db guys made FILEID primary on FILEHISTORY table and FILEID from FILES table references FILEHISTORY's FILEID as a foreign key.
Is that right?  Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: Does one file have multiple FileHistory entries? If so, then FileHistory needs to reference the File table (not the other way around....). The file that can contain multiple entries for the other way must be the child table, referencing the parent table

Comment: Unfortunetly, most of my questions are unaswered, so I can't accept much.

Answer (score 1):

Filehistory should be:

```
FILEHISTORY
id int not null primary key
fileid int (foreign key to files)
other fields
```

filename can be removed from filehistory as it's already available in files, which is linked by fileid.

This model allows one FILES to have multiple FILEHISTORY

Comment: Well, as far as I know FILEHISTORY can contain records without reference in FILES (these are invoice files that are not stored in DB and some other fields in FILEHISTORY).  Just what principle should I use determining (or arguing) which table is primary?

Comment: if you change the fileid (int) to allow NULL values, the table can be used on it's own, without requiring a link to FILES. From the layout I gathered this was only used for filenames, not invoice files. Maybe you could add a type to files (invoice, other, etc) or create new tables altogether for historytables that are not linked..

Comment: As a matter of fact FILEHISTORY does have FILETYPE field (char(1)) which is fully descriptive.  DB guys claim that this design worked for years and aren't going to change anything.  So, the question remains theoretical only(  I'm still certain that FILES should be the primary table (just as Oli suggested) and just to prevent FILES from containing entity without correspoding record in FILEHISTORY they could have written trigger for inserting some initial data about file.  (They want to always have corresponding record in FILEHISTORY)

Answer (score 1):

If you go by this design as proposed by your db guys, how does it take care of the fact that a  file can have multiple history records?

For example:

File A - created yesterday by you

File A - changed by me today

In this case, based on the schema below :-

```
FILEHISTORY
( FILEID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  FILENAME VARCHAR,
 some other fields)
```

There will be 2 records in FileHistory for File A - say with FileID= 1 and FileID = 2

Questions -

1. Which one of the 2 FileID's  (1 / 2 for File A) will be stored in "FileID" field in 
   "Files" table?
2. In this design, using the ID will no longer be sufficient for searching the entire history of a file (Maybe thats why FileHISTORY also has a FileName field as thats the only real way of searching for the entire history of a file - and that wouldnt be as efficient as searching on an ID instead of a string)
3. Also, is it possible that the file can get renamed? 
   If point 2 above is valid, then i guess that renaming a file will cause you to lose all history record for that file.

What I am trying to say here is that :

1. I think your approach of having the fileID as primary in FILES table is the better approach. I think it simulates the actual relationship of the files more realistically.
2. Depending on the requirements of your system, the proposed approach may work but it definitely will require more effort and there are some scenarios where it may potentially be more expensive / not be able to cater to.

Comment: As I learnt more about their system, after some time they actually delete record from FILES table, having FILEHISTORY record remain intact.

Comment: @Nick - Their approach just adds to the overhead - deleting records from FILES table is one more additional overhead. Also, that such a approach - not optimal even from a normalization perspective - should be proposed by "db guys" itself is very surprising to me. Usually, I have found data architects / db admin to be a lot more fastidious about their schema / normalization etc (and rightly so).